# LicenseCheckerCallback not calling

Tags: android

LicenseCheckerCallback  not calling back any of the function like allow, dont allow, or applicationerror

is there a problem with LVL cause i am using the latest one from under play_licensing

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "The public key";


private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] {random stuff};


private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;
private LicenseChecker mChecker;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
    mChecker = new LicenseChecker(
            this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
            new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
            BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
    if(something) {
        if (something) {
          ...
        }
        else{
            mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback); <----error
        }
    }
    else{
        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback); <---com.xxxx.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:67)
    }
}
....
private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
        @Override
        public void allow(int reason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }
            prefs.put("license", "Valid");
            OpenSet();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void dontAllow(int reason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }
           unlicensed(reason);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }
            unlicensed(Policy.RETRY);
        }
    }
}
```

So i dont have any crash, and the logcat says I/LicenseChecker: Received response.

but neither void allow, dontallow, applicationerror is running :/

Comment: have configured on google play developer console?

Comment: you can also check your code by switching off  the internet it will give the retry option

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi  yes i have configured it on the console, and switching off the internet does invoke help either.
I think it could be the google library fault?